# What does the meaning of 'we cashed in our loose change'?

Tags: meaning

could you tell me what it is?
ex>the bank where we cashed in our loose change every Saturday morning.

Comment: Exchanged coins for dollar bills perhaps.

Comment: @xaero2003 Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) may be of interest to you, as this site is geared towards questions from advanced users of English.

Answer (score 2):

A possible definition that you might be looking for is:

> Exchanging multiple coins/notes of a lower denomination for a higher denomination note/bill.

Eg. Exchanging four 25c coins for one dollar bill.

Answer (score 1):

In the context given, it would appear that the speaker was in the habit of exchanging assorted coins for banknotes.  Of course it's possible that "cashed in" could be construed as some other conversion, perhaps a bank deposit.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me with easy words? I'm not a native speaker and learning English.